# Different environments and data on cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I have a problem. I am using protractor-cucumber-framework.

I have for example this cucumber testcase on my feature file

```
Scenario: login successfully
    Given I am in mypage
    When I fill the fields with data
        | key | value |
        | user | userValue |
        | pass| passValue |
    And I push on login button
    Then I am logged in with my credentials
```

Given I have 3 environments (dev, test and live)

In dev I have: User1 and User2

In test I have: User3 and User4

In live I have: User5 and User6

I need to do a testcase for each user, 6 testcases in total.

The qwestion is: Is there any way to use the same Scenario cucumber for the 6 tests?.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert this into a **ScenarioOutline** and split the examples table into 3. Use a filter in the runner for the environment you want to run.

```
Scenario Outline: login successfully
    Given I am in mypage
    When I fill the fields with data
        | key | value |
        | user | <userValue> |
        | pass| <passValue> |
    And I push on login button
    Then I am logged in with my credentials

@dev
Examples:
|userValue|passValue|
|user1|pass1|
|user2|pass2|

@test
Examples:
|userValue|passValue|
|user3|pass3|
|user4|pass4|

@live
Examples:
|userValue|passValue|
|user5|pass5|
|user6|pass6|
```

Runner class to run **test** users. Change accordingly for the other two. I mentioned this in Java you need to change fro protractor.

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = { "@test" }, plugin = {""} 
    glue = "", features = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in WHY you are testing that you can login into the three different environments. Generally when testing you would be creating the accounts before trying to login. So in the test environment you would start off with an empty database and your scenario would be

```
Given I am registered
When I sign in
Then I should be signed in
```

The `Given` creates the account, the `When` uses the account to sign in, and the `Then` examines the UI too confirm you are signed in.

I have no idea why you would want to run this scenario against the development environment.

I can see that you might want to test that a production system has certain accounts on it, but that is a very different thing to testing you can login. Also running scenarios against a production environment is dangerous. So if you still want to do this I would insist that you use a separate scenario (ideally in a completely seperate set of features), as you really are testing different things

```
Scenario: Accounts exist on production

  ...

Scneario: I can login
  ...
```